# VBA issue filling in text fields in internet explorer

Tags: excel, internet-explorer, vba

I am attempting to write a segment of code in VBA that will allow me to open a website and login. The issue I'm having is that the username and password will fill in the correct boxes, but disappear before the button is pressed. I have tried adding a timer before the "button" section of code, but this just delays the inevitable! Here is my code so far:

```
'Declare constants
Const cURL = "website url"
Const cusername = "my username"
Const cpass = "my password"

'Declare Variables
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim iedoc As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

'Open internet explorer and navigate to website
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate cURL

'Wait for initial page to load
Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

'Populate the username and password fields
Set iedoc = IE.document

With iedoc.forms(0)
  .UserId.Value = cusername
  .Password.Value = cpass
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

Set ojbCollection = IE.document.getElementsByClassName("HippoButton__default__758acd9f5b27a3904664f41ba069d55a LoginComponents__loginButton__214681ee5e89039a688aeca993b3b95c")(0).Click

End With

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
```

And here is the HTML source code from the website:

```
<form>
<div class="LoginComponents__fullField__9ce1cf562b2ae67284a157be3b4f1c8d">
<label>User Id</label>
<input type="text" name="userId" value="" 
class="HippoInput__text__3a7f7c41dab2f6282c3d2416f11729c7 
HippoInput__invalid__18e2ce0e6d6a0c36106c94a2a7d06e29">
</div>
<div class="LoginComponents__fullField__9ce1cf562b2ae67284a157be3b4f1c8d">
<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" value="" 
class="HippoInput__text__3a7f7c41dab2f6282c3d2416f11729c7 
HippoInput__invalid__18e2ce0e6d6a0c36106c94a2a7d06e29">
</div>
<div 
class="LoginComponents__checkboxField__021cae0465786c49cfbe6782549172f2">
<input type="checkbox" name="rememberMe" 
class="HippoInput__checkbox__83aa5a268198870efcbb1bd13434d2af" value="on">
<label>Remember Me</label>
</div>
<div class="LoginComponents__fullField__9ce1cf562b2ae67284a157be3b4f1c8d">
<button class="HippoButton__default__758acd9f5b27a3904664f41ba069d55a 
LoginComponents__loginButton__214681ee5e89039a688aeca993b3b95c">Secure 
Login</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does `.UserId.Focus = cusername` accomplish?

Comment: @Jeeped Nothing, sorry I meant to remove them and completely forgot.

Comment: You have a typo. You declared `objCollection` then did `Set ojbCollection` (obj vs ojb)